# How to set value at Tensor index in batch

Tags: python, torch

I have a tensor of batch size N.

```
t = [[...], [....], [....] .... ]
```

In second tensor indices, I have N indices of elements I want to change in each tensor

```
indices = [i0, i1, i2 .... ]
```

So I want to have `t0` created from `t` via:

```
t0 = [[ set X at i0 ], [ set X at i1 ], [ set X at i2 ] .... ]
```

How can I do this at Torch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the following:

```
t[torch.arange(N),indices]
```

As an example:

```
import torch
a = torch.zeros((3,3))
a[torch.arange(3),[0,2,1]] = 0.2
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0.2000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.2000],
        [0.0000, 0.2000, 0.0000]])
```

*Note:* This behavior is the same as NumPy's [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

Comment: @Martin Your indices include all 3 columns, so of course the whole tensor changes. Try this: `vec = torch.zeros((5,5))`, `vec[:,[0,2,1]] = 0.2`.

Comment: My mistake, that's easy too; I'll change my answer

Comment: @Martin See my latest edit